# Merge [torrent] into [bittorrent]

Tags: discussion, tags, synonym-request

[torrent](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/torrent) has 242 questions, and a tag wiki that says:

> If your question is related to the BitTorrent peer-to-peer filesharing protocol, use [bittorrent] instead

However, every question that I saw in the tag was about BitTorrent, and it is unclear to me what the tag would be referring to aside from BitTorrent. Based on this, I suggest synonymizing [torrent](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/torrent) to [bittorrent](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/bittorrent) (which has 742 questions and an actual tag wiki).

Comment: I tend to agree.  In the early days I tried cleaning things up, but I couldn't keep up with the torrent of misuse.

Comment: bittorrent protocol or bittorrent client?

Comment: Torrent is the actual file ([technically the extension](http://www.bittorrent.org/beps/bep_0003.html) but informally a "torrent file"), bittorrent is the system/protocol/client.  But I don't see one without the other so merging makes sense.

Answer (score 4):

**NO**, we don't want to confuse a **protocol** with a **client** for that protocol.

"torrent" should be come "bittorrent-protocol"
and
"bittorrent-clients" should be added, at lest we can separate a protocol from the clients for it.

It's inconvenient that a client has the same name as the protocol itself but still separating the questions about a protocol from the questions about clients is a first step.

Comment: Each individual client's api already has its own tag. Any question involving bittorrent clients that don't involve using them programmatically are off-topic. A question about using a client's api also falls under [bittorent-protocol]. Why do we need a generic [bittorrent-clients] tag?

Comment: Bittorrent the program has no programmatic interface to speak of so it's off topic at SO. Moreover, it's actually just a rebranded version of uTorrent -- so it's also rather pointless to ask about.

Answer (score 3):

Bittorrent the program

- is merely a niche, rebranded version of uTorrent

  - so it's pointless to ask about it specifically as opposed to [utorrent](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/utorrent)
- has no programmatic interface to speak of apart from web ui

  - so asking about it is off topic at SO apart from very few, very specific cases

So I don't see a problem from [bittorrent](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/bittorrent) being about the protocol.

Answer (score -6):

## No

At least not before having a way to disambiguate BitTorrent the client from BitTorrent the protocol, otherwise we'd simply be shovelling problems into future us.

I would support renaming and synonimizing [torrent](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/torrent) to [bittorrent-protocol](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/bittorrent-protocol).

---

Chances are (also from summary examination) that actual [torrent](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/torrent) would be something like [bittorrent-protocol](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/bittorrent-protocol) and [bittorrent](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/bittorrent) might need to be split or at least generally eye-balled before retagging as either [bittorrent-protocol](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/bittorrent-protocol) and [bittorrent-client](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/bittorrent-client).

I leave the reader with opening questions such as what do we do with other bittorrent clients, do we pluralize [bittorrent-clients](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/bittorrent-clients) to get them all?

Comment: I feel like [bittorrent-client] will most likely be overrun with questions about writing your *own* bittorent client. I also don't really see the point for a tag specifically about the BitTorrent client, as it doesn't appear to have an API, nor can I find any preexisting questions using the client. The other [\*torrent\*] tags all refer to a specific library or API.

Comment: Are there any on-topic questions for the BitTorrent client, or any client?

Comment: @DanielWiddis there aren't any about the protocol itself from what I saw, only about clients. Specifically, specific clients api and libraries.

Comment: Plenty of on-topic questions about bittorrent clients, and how to use their APIs exist.  (Though, not, to my knowledge about the official BitTorrent Client as I don't think it offers a rich API like other clients.)

Comment: Ok, I agree with your reasonning @SuperStormer, except the part where you seem to imply that writing your *own* bittorrent client questions would be some kind of bad things to be overrun with? How is that not on topic? Or like, do you say that it would be a bad™ thing or am I misunderstanding?

Comment: Implementing a bittorrent client means writing software that implements the bittorrent protocol. I don't think there is a need to differentiate the tags in this particular case.

Comment: @FélixAdriyelGagnon-Grenier Apologies if I was unclear. What I meant was that your suggested tag name ([bittorent-client]) will most likely be used for DIY bittorrent clients, instead of *the* BitTorrent client (as in https://www.bittorrent.com/) as you intended.

Comment: Ah yes that's perfectly clear now thanks for the clarifications @SuperStormer.